# What does "Sion respectat dominus" mean?

Tags: medieval-latin, latin-to-english-translation

I want to ask a question about medieval Latin.

> *Sion respectat dominus*.

Does this sentence in English mean: "The lord gives some thought to Zion"? Is this translation correct?

This title is from Ekkehard of Aura. He was a medieval monk. He departed to the crusades in 1101. This sentence is from his book Hierosolimita in RHC V, PP. 1-40.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sentence literally means "the Lord looks back at Zion". *Dominus* = Lord, *respectat* = looks back at, *Sion* = Zion (indeclinable).

The verb *respectō* literally means "to look back at", but it can also mean "to wait for", "to care about", or even "to stare intently at". The exact meaning depends on context.

Answer (score 2):

Respectat can also mean respect, as that, etymologically, is where we get the word from, however the other translations I believe are more accurate